# Custom domain, DNS A Record Breaking old URL Paths

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm working on for a client and we created a website using a CMS template called Virb.com (sort of like squarespace.com). To get his custom URL to link to his new website, we needed to change an A record on his DNS that Virb gave us (IP ADDRESS). That worked fine.

'mywebsite.virb.com' now goes to 'mywebsite.com'

However, he'd been using his FTP long before Virb for file uploading/sharing, so he has a bunch of old folder directories (mostly image galleries or files he has for clients) on his FTP. All of those url links stopped working after the switch.

examples:
'mywebsite.com/imagegallery'
'mywebsite.com/download.zip'

So I'm wondering how can he have his URL point to the Virb A Record but still have his FTP/server IP address to get his old/new files/galleries to work properly? Right now I can't get both to work at the same time. Thank you for the help!

Comment: The URL "translation" is something your webserver/cms does. Also, your question is still a bit vague. Is this a new site? has it been moved? what has the FTP to do with this?

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not how DNS works, and as a professional admin with all the base knowledge (requiremet of this site as per FAQ) you should know. DNS has no knowledge of URL's.